# HSQLDB list all constraints

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, hsqldb

Does anyone know how to list all constraints, or query for a particular Foreign Key constraint e.g. FK1234567890 in HSQLDB?

In other databases there are special system tables for this, but I can't find anything on the docs for this one.

Thanks, N.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

HSQLDB system tables are listed in the Guide

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_information_schema

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS view has the overall information. Other tables list the columns used in constraints.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a clear text version of above explanation, that really works for my:

```
       SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
```

Comment: The table does not exist in my version, use `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS`

Answer (score 3):

You can find the contraint `FK1234567890` using this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'FK1234567890'
```

To see the columns related with the constraint:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE 
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME like 'FK1234567890'
```

Comment: You have a typo in the 1st select: CONTRAINT_NAME -> CONSTRAINT_NAME.